# Android: Checking if headphones are plugged in

Tags: android

How can I check if headphones are currently plugged in. I don't want a broadcastreceiver which informs me when they have been connected to the device. I need something like:

```
if(/*headphone is connected*/)
 ...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you'll be interested in the [`isWiredHeadsetOn()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isWiredHeadsetOn()) and [`isBluetoothA2dpOn()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isBluetoothA2dpOn()) of the [`AudioManager` class](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html).

However, the `isWiredHeadsetOn()` method is only available in Android 2.0 or later.  (The `isBluetoothA2dpOn()` method has been available since Android 1.5.)

Comment: Note that this is now deprecated and you need to check the types of `audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS)` instead

Answer (score 2):

Use this code snippet

```
AudioManager am1 = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
Log.i("am1.isWiredHeadsetOn()", am1.isWiredHeadsetOn()+"");
Log.i("am1.isMusicActive()", am1.isMusicActive()+"");
Log.i("am1.isSpeakerphoneOn()", am1.isSpeakerphoneOn()+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job at least on 1.6; not sure whether it's supported in later versions (a is an instance of AudioManager)

```
boolean headphones = (a.getRouting(a.getMode()) & AudioManager.ROUTE_HEADSET) == AudioManager.ROUTE_HEADSET;
```

Comment: @movillnescom with this sentence, do you check If headset is plugged or unplugged?