# Android earphone jack

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Checking if headphones are plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764733/android-checking-if-headphones-are-plugged-in)

Is there a way to check if earphones are connected to the Android device? Some kind of audio routing property or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to set up a BroadcastReceiver, looking for the "ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG" Intent.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG