# WebRTC ondevicechange workaround for mobile browser

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android, webrtc-ios

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/ondevicechange, the `ondevicechange` event is not supported in Chrome Android and Safari iOS.

So is there any alternative or workaround to detect device changes during a session?

Comment: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073392/how-to-check-in-browser-if-the-headphones-just-got-plugged-out)